# Получение штата по координатам

Tags: java

Нужно получить штат(USA) по координатам, без использования googlemap и желательно в оффлайн - режиме.

Comment: *без использования googlemap* яндекс-мап - устроит? Это сто пудов не гугло-мап.

Comment: желательно в оффлайн режиме

Comment: Т.е. вопрос в том, что вам нужна оффлайн база всех адресов в мире с привязкой к координатам?

Comment: Вообще задача стоит в определении штата по координатам

Comment: так и напишите прямо в вопросе, а не в комментарии, что, мол, требуется по географическим координатам определение административной единицы такого-то государства, причём в отсутствие связи с интернетом. дополнить вопрос можно, нажав [edit].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Самое простое, наверное:

1. Взять какую-то базу координат городов, например [geonames](http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/).
2. Построить по городам какой-нибудь [пространственный индекс](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_database#Spatial_index).
3. Искать город, который будет [ближайшим соседом](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0) к данной точке.

Другой вариант:

1. Найти/экспортировать в географическом векторном формате, например [KML](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/KML) границы штатов.
2. Проверять вхождение точки в границу каждого штата. Для ускорения - построить дополнительный пространственный индекс, чтобы уменьшить число кандидатов.